# Only one insert instead of 12

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `parts` and `items`. I like to create the `items` from the `parts`. The following request contains 12 ids. `$parts` return 12 models as expected.

But in the db, only the last one is stored:

PurchaseItemController

```
    public function storeAddedParts(StorePurchaseOrderItemRequest $request)
    {
        $parts = Part::whereIn('id', $request->added_part_ids)->get();

        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            $this->repo->create([
                'name' => $part->name
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Repository

```
    public $model;

    public function __construct(PurchaseOrderItem $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function create( $data)
    {
        $this->model->name = $data['name'];
        $this->model->creator_id = Auth()->id();
        $this->model->save();

        return $this->model;
    }
```

I do not understand, why only the last insert is saved.

Comment: You are passing a `PurchaseOrderItem` to your repository constructor and then updating it in the create method, should the create method not instantiate a new instance of `PurchaseOrderItem`? Atm it looks to me like your are updating the same `PurchaseOrderItem` 12 times, that's why you see the data of the last part in the database.

Comment: Thats right. Thanks Remul

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create many items at once like this:

In PurchaseItemController:

```php
    public function storeAddedParts(StorePurchaseOrderItemRequest $request)
    {
        $parts = Part::whereIn('id', $request->added_part_ids)->select('name')->toArray();

        PurchaseOrderItem::insert($parts);
    }
```